# facing issue to convert svg code from cart image

Tags: svg, converters

I have a cart image which I need to convert into svg code, anyone help me to convert the SVG inline code

Here is the image  which I want to convert to svg code

https://ibb.co/bJDHtjR

and I have sample SVG code but I tried to convert desired shape but I could not
here is SVG code

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30"  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="fill: white;display: flex;float: right;"><circle cx="176" cy="416" r="32"></circle><circle cx="400" cy="416" r="32"></circle><path d="M456.8 120.78a23.92 23.92 0 00-18.56-8.78H133.89l-6.13-34.78A16 16 0 00112 64H48a16 16 0 000 32h50.58l45.66 258.78A16 16 0 00160 368h256a16 16 0 000-32H173.42l-5.64-32h241.66A24.07 24.07 0 00433 284.71l28.8-144a24 24 0 00-5-19.93z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Your svg looks OK - but you can't see it as it has a white fill. Besides I highly recommend to compare already existing svg icon libraries (fontAwesome, Material Icons etc.) before converting anything to svg (e.g png to svg)